# System.StringException: Ending position out of bounds:

Tags: string, substring

I am getting the titled error

> System.StringException: Ending position out of bounds:99

for the below code:

```
CusObj2.ProdName__c=CusObj2.Name__c.substring(0,99);
```

All I want to do is truncate the name in this trigger to 99 characters or fewer. Please advise.

Pls note I am getting this error only when deploying a change set - it passes the same testClass in my sandbox.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The abbreviate method is a good choice:

```
CusObj2.ProdName__c = CusObj2.Name__c.abbrevate(99);
```

as it:

> Returns an abbreviated version of the String, of the specified length
>   and with ellipses appended if the current String is longer than the
>   specified length; otherwise, returns the original String without
>   ellipses.

where ellipses means three dots.

**PS**

Or if `Name__c` can be null:

```
CusObj2.ProdName__c = CusObj2.Name__c != null ? CusObj2.Name__c.abbrevate(99) : null;
```

Comment: `string.left(99)` if you don't care about the ellipses.

Comment: what if the string is null?

Comment: Or, more likely in most use cases - `CusObj2__c.ProdName__c = CusObj2__c.Name__c.abbreviate(CusObj2__c.ProdName.getDescribe().getLength());` _(ex the null check)_